# Ensuring a template class isn't polymorphic?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, static-assert

I was recently working on a C++ library where I was designing a template class that, for efficiency and safety reasons, needed to specifically be non-polymorphic. To ensure that later on I didn't forget this and accidentally break everything, I thought I'd be a good citizen and add a static assertion to that effect.

I initially tried something like this:

```
template <typename T> class VirtualVerboten {
     ...

     static_assert(!std::is_polymorphic<VirtualVerboten>::value,
                   "This should not be polymorphic."); // Error!
};
```

This doesn't compile because, at the time that I'm using `VirtualVerboten`, it's an incomplete type. If this were a non-template class, I'd just put the `static_assert` right after the type:

```
class NonTemplateVirtualVerboten {
   ...
}
static_assert(!std::is_polymorphic<NonTemplateVirtualVerboten>::value,
              "This should not be polymorphic.");
```

But since this is a template class, the analogous idea of making a "template `static_assert`" isn't legal:

```
template <typename T> class VirtualVerboten {
     ...

};

template <typename T>              
static_assert(!std::is_polymorphic<VirtualVerboten>::value,
              "This should not be polymorphic."); // Error!
```

The solution I came up with was to find a member function inside of `VirtualVerboten` that would likely be used when the template was instantiated (specifically, the constructor), then put the static assertion in there:

```
template <typename T> class VirtualVerboten {
     VirtualVerboten();
};

template <typename T>
VirtualVerboten<T>::VirtualVerboten() {
  static_assert(!std::is_polymorphic<VirtualVerboten>::value,
                "This should not be polymorphic."); // Yay!
  doSomeActualThingsAtRuntime();
}
```

This works, except that it relies on the fact that this particular constructor will actually be invoked and therefore instantiated, which fails if there are multiple constructors that could be called.

Is there a "foolproof" way to add this static assertion here? I understand why the original code was producing an error and why you can't have a template static assertion, so this is more of a "did I miss another way of doing this?" rather than a "here's why what you did doesn't work."

Comment: Uhh? Constructor? Have to construct the class, somehow, somewhere. Shove your static assert in there.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's what I ended up doing. Perhaps I should edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: You just need to package the type in something dependent so the static assertion is only checked in the second phase.

Comment: @KerrekSB Could you post something like that as an answer here?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik To follow up, the issue is that if there are multiple constructors, I'd need to put the static assertion or something that triggers it into every single one of them.

Comment: I can think of at least two approaches to avoid code duplication with multiple constructors: 1. Delegating constructors. 2. An instance of an inner class that's empty, except for a default constructor with the static assert.

Comment: Seems like the dtor might be a better choice. Only one of them to worry about (i.e. no overloading).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's already indicated by [@JerryCoffin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389968/ensuring-a-template-class-isnt-polymorphic#comment69986976_41389968). The best way is to use the `static_assert` in a destructor. i.e.

```
template <typename T> 
class VirtualVerboten {
public: 
  ~VirtualVerboten() {
    static_assert(!std::is_polymorphic<VirtualVerboten>::value,
                  "This should not be polymorphic.");
   }
};
```

Since destructor can be only 1, it's guaranteed that the `static_assert` is checked whenever there is an instantiation of its object.

---

IMO, another elegant way is to create a utility class & inherit the same, such as:

```
template<typename T>
struct NonPolymorphic
{
  ~NonPolymorphic() 
  { static_assert(!std::is_polymorphic<T>::value, "This should not be polymorphic."); }
};

template <typename T> 
class VirtualVerboten : NonPolymorphic<VirtualVerboten<T>>
{
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `final` keyword is a C++14 feature that disallows classes from being inherited. If the class is inherited, the code will not compile. Example:

```
template <typename T>
class VirtualVerboten final {
  ...
}
```

If anyone tries to inherit it...

```
class Derived : public VirtualVerboten<int> {
  ...
}
```

The compiler will complain

Comment: The question is about polymorphism, not inheritance. True the two are very closely related, but inheritance without polymorphism (i.e. use of virtual functions) is possible. cppreference describes the `is_polymorphic` type trait as `a non-union class that declares or inherits at least one virtual function`. Which should give a clue about the types of classes the OP is trying to exclude.

Comment: Oddly enough, in the case I'm considering we do use inheritance but have to not use polymorphism, so this approach won't actually work in my case.